# Is it ok to add my css class to an element that has a bootstrap row or col class

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I thought I had heard or read a long time ago that you are not supposed to mix bootstrap rows and cols with personal css on the same element because it can cause unexpected results. But I have tried multiple searches wording it lots of different ways but keep getting the same results, none of which answer my question. Is it ok to do this:

```
    <div class="my-padding-css-class row">
       <div class="my-width-css-class col-md-6">
       </div>
       <div class="my-margin-css-class col-md-6">
       </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried wording it in multiple different ways in a google search, flipped through the bootstrap docs, as well as looked through here on SO.  The results I got from my searches came back  as mixing col and row together or combining scss with B.S., or adding B.S. and an external stylesheet to the same page, but never anything about combining B.S. row or col class with personal css class in the same element.

Comment: You will see a combination of opinion based and results based answers. When I'm using Bootstrap, I use a combination of techniques it all depends on my CSS. If I'm adding borders or backgrounds for example on something that uses a row/col, I will add another div with my personal CSS as a class. There is no right/wrong answer as it is situation based.

Comment: To answer the question in your title, yes, it's 100% fine. The only thing you need to worry about is your CSS possibly taking precedence over Bootstrap's. Totally depends on your specific situation

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap classes are predefined to help you get something quickly. But if you need further changes to an element then I think it is totally OK to add more classes where necessary and write your own codes to make the change.